# How avoid change tab in QTabWidget | PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a tab with the name "+" in which if I click on it opens a ApplicationModal window for configurate the content in that tab. I want to avoid the change of tab when i click in it until press "Accept" in the ApplicationModal window. How can I block this change? I don't know if I explain me.

[image]

This it's de code

tabs.py for the MainWindow

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(628, 504)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 34, 541, 396))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "")
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 628, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab1), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab2), _translate("MainWindow", "+"))
```

win0.py for the ApplicationModal window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Win0(object):
    def setupUi(self, Win0):
        Win0.setObjectName("Win0")
        Win0.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        Win0.resize(255, 203)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Win0)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 9, 154, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.accpet_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.accpet_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 130, 75, 23))
        self.accpet_button.setObjectName("accpet_button")
        self.cancel_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cancel_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 131, 75, 23))
        self.cancel_button.setObjectName("cancel_button")
        Win0.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Win0)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 255, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Win0.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Win0)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Win0.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Win0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Win0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Win0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Win0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Win0", "New Window"))
        self.accpet_button.setText(_translate("Win0", "Accept"))
        self.cancel_button.setText(_translate("Win0", "Cancel"))
```

And the main.py for develop the functionality

```
from tabs import Ui_MainWindow
from win0 import Ui_Win0
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Win0(Ui_Win0):
    win0 = None
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win0 = win
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self.win0)

class Main(Ui_MainWindow):
    win0 = None
    win1 = None
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self.win)
        self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.tabClick)

    def tabClick(self, event):
        if event == 1:
            print("New tab")
            self.win1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            new_window = Win0(self.win1)
            self.win1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Main(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please avoid deleting a post if you only want to do some minor editing, and just modify the existing one.

Comment: You use setWindowModality to prevent the parent window from being operated, right?

Comment: @dudulu Yes, I seted it to a ApplicationModal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a window that blocks the others until it's closed, you're looking for a *modal dialog*.

> A modal window creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it visible, with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users must interact with the modal window before they can return to the parent application. This avoids interrupting the workflow on the main window.

<sub>[From the [wikipedia article about modal windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)]</sub>

It is relatively easy to achieve that in Qt, by using a [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html).

Designer already provides two basic templates with basic Ok/Cancel buttons when you create a new form, so create a new dialog with buttons on right or bottom (this will automatically connect the button box with the dialog's accept/reject slots), add the combobox, save and convert the file with `pyuic` (in the following example, I exported the file as `dialog.py` and used the default `Ui_Dialog`).

Then the implementation is very easy. The important thing is to add the *parent* argument to the QDialog instance: this ensures that the dialog uses the parent as a *reference* for the "window modality", so that that parent is *blocked* until the dialog is closed by *accepting* or *rejecting* it (*rejection* is usually done by clicking on a `RejectRole` button like <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or by closing the dialog in any way, including pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Do note that I changed your approach by using multiple inheritance in order to make things easier (see the guidelines on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) about this approach, which is usually the better and most suggested method when using `pyuic` generated files).

```
from tabs import Ui_MainWindow
from dialog import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class SelectDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.tabClick)

    def tabClick(self, tab):
        if tab == 1:
            dialog = SelectDialog(self)
            if dialog.exec_():
                print(dialog.comboBox.currentIndex())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Main()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```